# How can I improve the code for my responsive video mask SVG logo to make it cleaner and more efficient?

Tags: css, svg, mask

I created an SVG logo with a video in the background using only HTML and CSS. However, I feel that the implementation may not be optimal because I had to set the height to 900px to make the logo appear at 100% size. Additionally, I had to use a margin-top of -290px to make it work, as simply using 100% width and height auto did not produce the desired result. After experimenting with various approaches, this method seemed to be the most effective thus far.

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
}

video {
  width: 100%;
  height: 436px;
  margin-top: 111px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
  object-fit: cover;
  -webkit-mask-image: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/2f/Google_2015_logo.svg);
  mask-image: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/2f/Google_2015_logo.svg);
  -webkit-mask-mode: alpha;
  mask-mode: alpha;
  -webkit-mask-size: cover;
  mask-size: cover;
  -webkit-mask-repeat: no-repeat;
  mask-repeat: no-repeat;
}

@media (max-width: 575.98px) { 
  video {
    width: 100%;
    height: 111px;
    margin-top: 0px;
}
 }
```

```html
<div class="container">
      <video src="https://videos.ctfassets.net/mq81gy7w2znw/6w4zLGGSLzp0D9jv0R9WLL/cd41a8f121a48b4d9a74f1a731d067db/header_vid_-_1080_v3.m4v" autoplay loop muted>
      </video>
    </div>
```

Comment: I guess that the SVG used as a mask in the example is not the actual SVG that you use in your code. The example code (primary the CSS) looks fine to me (except defining both width and height and in different units), but maybe there could be something in your SVG that could be optimized. Could you at least add part of your SVG to the question?

Comment: @chrwahl I think my question may not have been clear enough, but I got the desired result technically. However, I believe there's a better way to achieve it without using unusually large width and height values. I've seen tutorials where they use text instead of SVG, but the problem is that I'm using a custom font that I don't have on my laptop. So, I had to use an SVG file and adjust the video's shape, also the margin-top: 111px property is weird. Is there a simpler and more efficient CSS and HTML structure to achieve the same result?